# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main - how to fix it?

Tags: java

Please help me to fix my simple program. I'm just newbie of Java Programming. When i write the program, and the program has been success compile but can't run cause the massage error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main" has been show. Everybody can help me to run this program ?

The coding is:

Person class...

```
//Program to display student details using inheritance
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
}
```

Student class...

```
class Student extends Person
{
    int mark1,mark2,mark3;
    void putdata()
    {
        System.out.println("Name = " + name);
        System.out.println("Age = " + age);
        System.out.println("Mark1 = " + mark1);
        System.out.println("Mark2 = " + mark2);
        System.out.println("Mark3 = " + mark3);
    }
 }
```

Marks class...

```
class Marks
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Student obj1=new Student();
        obj1.name="Sultanah";
        obj1.age=17;
        obj1.mark1=67;
        obj1.mark2=87;
        obj1.mark3=97;
        obj1.putdata();
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are running it? One thing anyway. Class Marks should be public and name of the file should be Marks.java

Comment: I copied you code and it runs just fine.  How are you running it?  Did you include the .class or .java extension on the commandline?

Comment: @JaydeepPatel Wrong on both counts.

Answer (score 1):

JVM when try to launch the program looks for the class with the same name as the name passed to run the program. Once the class is found then it looks for the `main` method  in it. So make sure that you are running the program using `Mark` as the class name because that is the class that contains your main method.

Comment: No, it doesn't 'look for the public class in the file'. It looks for the class named in the command, public or otherwise.

Comment: What file name? It looks for the class named on the command line. Period.

Comment: I have no issue running the code as is...the "Main" class doesn't need to be `public`...

Comment: i save the file as Student.java and trying to compile and run at cmd with student.java but the error has been show like above of my problem. So what my problem? Thanks

Comment: @RogManJiwaMerdeka See my answer. Ignore this ever-changing moveable feast. Who knows what it says by now?

Comment: Thanks a lot all that give me answer. Got it the causes and has been run the program. 

I changed the class Marks to public class Marks. and save the file as Marks.java. Before i compile and want to run the program as Student.java. Maybe the problem from there. 

However, thanks all. Your are boss of Programming. :)

Comment: @RogManJiwaMerdeka Blimey. Did you *really* read it? All you had to do was `java Marks`.

Answer (score 1):

*Either:*

1. Your `main()` method shoudl be placed in the `Student` class, if that's the class you're executing, *or*
2. You should be executing the class that does contain the `main()` method, i.e. `Marks`.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you trying to run class that doesn't have main method. according to your code Marks.java has     main method so after compilation you can run Marks class using

```
java Marks
```

Comment: Wrong on both counts. Did you read the other answers, and the comments?

Comment: Surprisingly, the `javac` won't care what the name of the java file is, it will create `Marks.class` file regardless...also, EJP is right, the class doesn't need to be public

Comment: Still wrong. There's no evidence in the question that he has a Marks.java file at all. Indeed your initial answer assumed that he didn't. When and if you read his comments elsewhere, you'll find that he doesn't.